# How do I catch PostGIS/PostgreSQL RAISE messages in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a trigger set up in PostGIS/PostgreSQL which will show a `RAISE WARNING` when an inserted or updated polygon is within a certain distance of some predefined planning constraints. I want this warning to be sent to QGIS to alert a user to the proximity warning, but with a `WARNING` this does not occur. On the other hand, using `RAISE EXCEPTION` shows an error in the QGIS message bar but doesn't allow the insert/update to be committed (which I want - it should be a warning, not an error).

Example of the messages I want to be sent to QGIS:

```
CREATE TABLE input_table (
    id serial,
    geom geometry
             );

CREATE TABLE listed_buildings (
    id serial,
    geom geometry
             );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_constraint_proximity()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
declare
dist_lb real;
begin
    dist_lb := (select st_distance(new.geom, st_collect(listed_buildings.geom)) from listed_buildings);

    if dist_lb <= 3 then
        RAISE WARNING 'Check planning boundary - it is within approx %m of a listed building', round(dist_lb);
    end if;
    if dist_lb <= 1 then
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Check planning boundary - it is within approx %m of a listed building', round(dist_lb);
    end if;
    RETURN new;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_constraint_proximity_trigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON input_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_constraint_proximity();

insert into listed_buildings (geom) values (st_geomfromewkt('polygon((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'));

insert into input_table (geom) values (st_geomfromewkt('polygon((2 2, 2 3, 3 3, 3 2, 2 2))'));
insert into input_table (geom) values (st_geomfromewkt('polygon((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'));
```

Comment: These are asynchronous notifications. They get delivered to the client, but the client application has to know to read them. What client driver does qgis use? PgJDBC? nPgSQL? psqlODBC? Direct `libpq`?

Comment: It uses libpq directly: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.devel/4953
Hopefully a QGIS dev can help here then.