# Show "Raise Notice" and "Raise Warning" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, trigger

Is there a way to catch "Raise Warning" and "Raise Notice" (while editing PostGIS-Layers) from a PostgreSQL/PostGIS-Trigger-Function within QGIS?
One example: I have a trigger that reacts to insert or update-events and sends back notices to the client.In QGIS i just get messages from raise exeption but not notices or warnings.

I found a old question ( [How do I catch PostGIS/PostgreSQL RAISE messages in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89287/how-do-i-catch-postgis-postgresql-raise-messages-in-qgis) ) but I can't imagine that QGIS is still not capable of catching these important "feedbacks" from the Database, especially as it has its origin in working together with PostGIS.
Does anyone know more about that?

Comment: Is there a ticket in the bug tracker for handling such events?

Comment: Just a thought on a halfway workaround. Can you raise the warning and notice as an exception in Postgresql. That is use the exception to deliver the warning and notice to QGIS

Comment: @NathanW No not as far as I know. Can I open a ticket there or does this has to be tone by a developer?

Comment: @Jacob thanks for the workaround idea but I want to make a difference between notices/warnings and exeptions. The best option would be if the notices would be displayed like in a console, so that I could inform the user how many loops already are done and how many are left...

Comment: You can open one here http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be implemented in the meantime: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12184#change-59414

Comment: link not working