# QGIS plpgsql RAISE MESSAGEs do not appear in QGIS Log Messages Panel | PostGIS Tab

Tags: qgis, postgis, trigger, plpgsql

I refer to this post [Show "Raise Notice" and "Raise Warning" in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133963/show-raise-notice-and-raise-warning-in-qgis) and to the herein referred issue https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12184#change-59414.

Using QGIS 2.18.18 LTR I try to display plpgsql RAISE MESSAGES from trigger functions and I think they should appear in the QGIS *Log Messages Panel*, *PostGIS*-Tab but they don't.

Is this the place for me to expect my plpgsql messages or do I miss something?